# How to iterate through a collection of instances of a class and access its template member

Tags: c++, templates, comparison, set

So, I have got the following classes and methods:

**Property**: Has a single member of type `int` (named `mTag`)

**TypedProperty**: Inherits from the `Property` class and adds a member called `mValue` of type `T` to it.

**PropertyList**: A class which Maintains a `std::set` of `Property` and has an `Add` and `Print` method.

**CheckSubset**: A method which checks if a `std::set` is included in another set.

I don't know how I should implement the `CheckSubset` method. Because I do not know how to iterate through a `set<Property>` and access to the template member (`mValue`). I also tried to use the `includes` method, which did not work (even if it worked, I would have no idea how it did!). The same problem exists in the `PropertyList::Print` method, where I do not know what cast should be used.
Any advice on the implementation of `CheckSubset` and `Print` methods would be appreciated!

**Updated** source code (using pointer)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tr1/memory>

using namespace std;

/////////////////// Property Class //////////////////////

class Property
{
public:
    Property(){};
    Property(const int tag)
            : mTag(tag) {}
    virtual ~Property() {}
    int mTag;
    bool operator<(const Property &property) const
    {
        return mTag < property.mTag;
    }
};

/////////////////// TypedProperty Class /////////////////

template< typename T >
class TypedProperty : public Property
{
public:
    TypedProperty (const int tag, const T& value)
            : Property(tag), mValue(value){}
    T mValue;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Property> PropertyPtr;

/////////////////// PropertyList Class /////////////////

class PropertyList
{
public:
    PropertyList(){};
    virtual ~PropertyList(){};
    template <class T>
    void Add(int tag, T value) 
    {
    PropertyPtr ptr(new TypedProperty<T>(tag, value));
        mProperties.insert(ptr);
    }
    void Print()
    {
    for(set<PropertyPtr>::iterator itr = mProperties.begin(); itr != mProperties.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout << ((PropertyPtr)*itr)->mTag << endl; 
        // What should I do to print mValue? I do not know its type
        // what should *itr be cast to? 
    }
    }
    set<PropertyPtr> mProperties;
};

//////////////////// Check Subset ///////////////////////
/*
 * Checks if subset is included in superset 
 */
bool CheckSubset(set<PropertyPtr> &superset, set<PropertyPtr> &subset)
{
    // How can I iterate over superset and subset values while I do not know
    // the type of mValue inside each Property?
    // I also tried the following method which does not seem to work correctly
    return includes(superset.begin(), superset.end(), 
            subset.begin(), subset.end());
}

int main()
{
    PropertyList properties1;
    properties1.Add(1, "hello");
    properties1.Add(2, 12);
    properties1.Add(3, 34);
    properties1.Add(4, "bye");

    properties1.Print();

    PropertyList properties2;
    properties2.Add(1, "hello");
    properties2.Add(3, 34);


    if(CheckSubset(properties1.mProperties, properties2.mProperties)) // should be true
        cout << "properties2 is subset!" << endl;

    PropertyList properties3;
    properties3.Add(1, "hello");
    properties3.Add(4, 1234);

    if(CheckSubset(properties1.mProperties, properties3.mProperties)) // should be false
        cout << "properties3 is subset!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Small point about `void Add(int tag, T value)`: why not `const T& value` just like you did in `TypedProperty`'s constructor. But that's almost nitpicking.

Comment: @Sjoerd If I use `const T& value`, I get this error: **error: array used as initializer** for this line: `properties1.Add(1, "hello");`

Comment: The usual C-string vs C++-strings. A single, additional overload `void Add(int tag, const char* value) { mProperties.insert(TypedProperty<std::string>(tag, value)); }` might solve that. But one wonders whether the cure is worse than the original problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving the problem in `Print` method of `PropertyList`, you could write a `Print` method for `TypedProperty` class, which prints its tag and value.

But about the problem in accessing `mValue` which you want to do some operations on, I can't think of a way using normal types and templates to get the `mValue` without engaging your parent class `Property` with template type of `TypedProperty` (which seems undesirable). But you could get the address of `mValue` and cast it to `void*` to eliminate the type problem. This way you will face another problem, that you can not point to value of a `void*` pointer, so you can not work with your pointer in parent level. Therefore, you should write a method (implemented by `TypedProperty`) that takes a `void*` pointer and casts it to the type defined in child and perform the desired operation.

For example in the following code, I assumed you want to check equality of a value in a `TypedProperty` with another one of the same type (`IsEqual` method).

Now you can implement simply `CheckSubset` using `IsEqual` (checking two elements would be like: `superItr->IsEqual(subItr->GetValue())`).

```
class Property
{
    public:
        Property(){};
        Property(const int tag)
            : mTag(tag) {}
        virtual ~Property() {}
        virtual void* GetValue() = 0;
        virtual bool IsEqual(void* value) = 0;
        virtual void Print() = 0;
        int mTag;
        bool operator<(const Property &property) const
        {
            return mTag < property.mTag;
        }
};


template< typename T >
class TypedProperty : public Property
{
    public:
        TypedProperty (const int tag, const T& value)
            : Property(tag), mValue(value){}
        void* GetValue()
        {
            return &mValue;
        }
        bool IsEqual(void* value)
        {
            return *((T*)value) == mValue;
        }
        void Print()
        {
            cout << "Tag: " <<  mTag << ", Value: " << mValue << endl;
        }
        T mValue;
};

typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Property> PropertyPtr;

class PropertyList
{
    public:
        PropertyList(){};
        virtual ~PropertyList(){};
        template <class T>
            void Add(int tag, T value) 
            {
                PropertyPtr ptr(new TypedProperty<T>(tag, value));
                mProperties.insert(ptr);
            }
        void Print()
        {
            cout << "-----------" << endl;
            for(set<PropertyPtr>::iterator itr = mProperties.begin(); itr != mProperties.end(); itr++)
            {
                (*itr)->Print();
            }
        }
        set<PropertyPtr> mProperties;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want, cannot be done with the current design.

Your approach fails with `std::set<Property>`.

`std::set<Property>` will slice. That means that it will only copy the `Property` part and forget to copy the additional `TypedProperty<T>` members.

As a result, inside `PropertyList::print()`, there is no way to access the mValue.

If you want to store `TypedProperty<T>`s inside a `std::set`, you must use some sort of pointer. I.e. either `std::set<Property*>`, or a smart pointer version.

Comment: I still cannot figure out how to implement the `Print` and `CheckSubset` methods given my data is stored in `std::set<Property*>`. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Meysam Two options: 1) To switch on mTag and each case will have a different cast. 2) Add a `virtual void print(std::ostream &os) const = 0` to Property and a `void print(std::ostream &os) const { os << mValue; }` in `TypedProperty`. I prefer the latter. `CheckSubset()` could do a simular trick: either a large switch with lots of casts, or one additional virtual function in the base class, although the fact that one could compare `TypedProperty<int>` with `TypedProperty<std::string>` will complicate matters (but I think they are solvable with a check on mTag and a single cast).

Comment: @Meysam As it is hard to answer your question in a single comment, maybe you could turn it into a new question, with a link to this question in the introduction of your question. I think you'll get better answers that way.